# Modeling with Knife, Loop Cut and Inset

Tags: modeling, workflow

The result of using **Bevel** and then **Inset** <kbd>I</kbd> should be as seen outlined in red.
However when I click <kbd>I</kbd> it will does not do anything of the sort.

[image]

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: You are in edge select mode.  Try it with faces selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After pressing <kbd>I</kbd> (I like independence) to ***[inset faces](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset)*** hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button (and move the cursor upwards) to add some depth to the faces and achieve the result you want.
[image]

Comment: They don't tell you that in the tutorial! Thanks!