# Shading Issues after knife project

Tags: shaders, knife-tool

Just starting out in the world of Blender 3d and I am trying to replicate the bottle below but am having difficulty creating the ridges that go around the centre of the bottle.

​I have tried a couple of different ways of doing this but am having difficulty in finding any tutorials similar to my needs and also I am not sure on the terminology I need to use in order to search for the issues I'm having.

[image: ATTEMPT 1]

Attempt 1 (above)

Creating the bottle shape then using the Knife project with 'cut through' selected to create the ridges

then bevelling each individual ridge but have an issue with the shading where the vertical edges meet the bevelled curve on the ridge and in the centre.

Attempt 2 (below)

Creating a cylinder bottle, then again using the knife project with 'cut through' selected to create the ridges

then adding adding a lattice modifier to create the shape of the bottle but again still with the same shading results after adding a bevel.

[image]

So my question is am I creating this in the correct way (knife project) and I need clean up the mesh or is there 'simpler' way of creating this?

​As I said I am very new to Blender 3d so I apologise for the vagueness of the question but am very keen to learn the correct way of doing things at the start so not to get into bad habits. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: A bit related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48910/modeling-with-knife-loop-cut-and-inset

Comment: What modifiers do you have enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add additional loop, and leave it on the surface:

[image]

It will add transition between main surface and the edges

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you add the edge loop at an angle though?

Comment: @GarethRichards It's just another knife cut